# How to generate session after user login in express-session?

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am using express.js , express-mysql-session and passport.js. The express session middleware is creating session for the static file requests such as login page which is creating another entry in the session table.

I have moved the static middleware before the express session middleware. But when I make a login request after moving the static middleware before the session middleware the passport throws an error "passport.initialize middlware not in use".

I guessing that this might be happening because there is no "connect.sid" cookie in the request!

That's how my configure function looks like

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.set('mode', process.argv[2] || 'local');
  app.set('port', config.port || 8080);
  app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  // this is a route handler for serving public file incase user doesn't have session
  app.get("/*", policies.publicRoute.handleRoute());

  app.use(busboy({
    limits: {
      fileSize: maxFileSize,
      files : 1
    }
  }));

  //create session store
  var sessionStore = new SessionStore({}, connection);
  // required for passport
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'mySecret',
    cookie: { maxAge : myNumber },
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
});
```

Comment: You need to show the relevant bits of your app.js file I guess. FWIW the usual order of things is something like this: `app.use(passport.initialize()); app.use(passport.session());` (... and make sure your body parsing is before all that).

Comment: I have added my app.configure function. The passport.initialize error happens when the request object doesn't have the connect.sid cookie property.